# Is my table is stored as heap or b-tree?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database. It’s .MDF & .LDF can be downloaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj2mw410jm2m078/MyDB.rar?dl=0

Now I want to know whether two table are stored as heap or b-tree(linked list), so I run the following commands:

```
USE CR_YPLS8_NEW_QB;

select 
    sys.objects.name, 
    sys.objects.object_id,
    sys.partitions.index_id,
    sys.system_internals_allocation_units.first_page,
    sys.system_internals_allocation_units.first_iam_page
from 
    sys.objects, sys.partitions, sys.system_internals_allocation_units
where 
    (sys.partitions.object_id = sys.objects.object_id) and   
    (sys.system_internals_allocation_units.container_id = sys.partitions.partition_id) and
    ((name = 'cardfa') or (name = 'pcspkc'));
```

Where 'cardfa' and 'pcspkc' are the two user tables I want to investigate.

The result is below:

[image: table result]

Based on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051%28v=sql.105%29.aspx, since both table’s index_id is 1, they are all stored as b-tree(the data pages in the leaf level is in linked list).

However, in the result table, the first row has first_page value (filenum, pagenum) = (1, 0x6F2A8) which is an invalid pointer.

The second row has first_page value (filenum, pagenum) = (1, 0x5941) = (1, 22849).

After I using the following commands:

DBCC TRACEON(3604);
DBCC page(CR_YPLS8_NEW_QB, 1, 22849, 3);

I get the following result:

[image: dbcc page result]

After checking each column in each slot, I find the data is completely different from the actual data stored in 'cardfa' table. So the first_page for the second row is also invalid.

And I then find the 'cardfa' table is actually stored in heap and can be referenced by first_iam_page instead of first_page, which is inconsistent with the search result. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your table has a clustered index it is stored as a [b-tree](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/livingforsqlserver/2010/12/27/sql-server-storage-internals-part-5-properties-of-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-pages/) otherwise it is a [heap](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/livingforsqlserver/2010/12/19/sql-server-storage-internals-part-3-architecture-of-heap-structure/).